# 'int' object not iterable error: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, and I am trying to run the code given below. But it keeps throwing an error:

> int object not iterable.

I want to calculate the sum of sqaures in an array. Here is the code. The variable `product` is already defined, so that is not the worrisome part.

```
def sumofsquares(x1):
    result=[]
    for i in range (len(x1)):
        result.append(sum((x1)[i]**2))
    return result

print (sumofsquares(product))
```

Comment: 1. Please fix the indentation. 2. What is `product`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming product is a `list` containing the numbers you want to find the sum of sqaures, you can iterate through the `list` and calculate squares of each number and add it to a list called `result`. At last you can return the sum of that list.

In codes you can do like this..

```
def sumofsquares(x1):
    result = [] # list to store squares of each number

    for i in range(len(x1)): # iterating through the list
        result.append(x1[i] ** 2) # squaring each number and appending to the list

    return (sum(result)) # returning the sum of the list

product = [1, 2, 3] # declaring the array to find sum of sqaure
print (sumofsquares(product)) # calling the function and displaying the return value

# Output
14
```

Hope this helps.!!

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked perfectly fine. Also, can you please explain the logic behind the given error? So that I can understand it better.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped. Accept and upvote the answer if it did.

Comment: Also, you were doing `result.append(sum((x1)[i]**2))` which will also give you an error. Because the list item must be acessed like `listname[index]`. Also, the `sum` function must be applied to a `list` or more than 1 number.

Comment: Let me know if you have further queries about the error.!